# tailwind utility class not rendering style if returned from an external function

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I am using Laravel 10 InertiaJS vue3 tailwind 3.3.6 if it matters.

I want to put my wrapper class as an export so that it can be used on multiple pages.

wrapper-class.js:

```
function sectionWrapperClass() {
    return "m-10 py-3 mx-auto w-1/2";
}

export { sectionWrapperClass };
```

Component.vue

```
<script setup>
import { computed } from "vue";
import { sectionWrapperClass } from "./wrapper-classes.js";

const sectionClass = computed(() => {
    return sectionWrapperClass();
});
</script>

<template>
    <div :class="sectionClass">
        <div class="mb-5 font-bold">{{ props.title }}</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I can see the class being written in the div but the style from tailwind is not applied. I am still new to tailwind so I may have missed some things.

Though I can do the snippet below and it will render the correct style.

```
const sectionClass = computed(() => {
    return "m-10 py-3 mx-auto w-1/2";
});
```

Another weird thing about this is:

1. component A `return "m-10 py-3 mx-auto w-1/2";`
2. component B `return sectionWrapperClass();`
3. component C `return sectionWrapperClass();`

If the classes are used like above, then all 3 components will have the their classes apply the styles. I did hear that tailwind will only load classes that are used in the application.

Correct me if I am wrong but does tailwind only uses the classes that was initially loaded? succeeding classes are not part of the final css ?

[image: Developer tool where m-10 class has no style found]

Comment: have you add the directory into **content** property inside tailwind.config.js? [take a look at this reference](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel)

Comment: if this is about tailwind setup, then no since this was built using laravel starter kit and tailwind was already included.

Comment: As per @mdzk, consider adding the directory into `content` property inside `tailwind.config.js`, [take a look at this reference](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel) and [more details about configuring `content` properly](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration).

Comment: I believe these things are already preconfigured by laravel's starter kit (inertiajs vue) content . Not an exact value since the documentation is showing blade while I am using vue

Answer (score 1):

The default Tailwind config of Laravel Inertia ( Breeze or Jetstream) does not automatically scan Tailwind classes added on JS files by default.

You can see it here [Jetstream](https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/blob/4.x/stubs/inertia/tailwind.config.js) and [Breeze](https://github.com/laravel/breeze/blob/1.x/stubs/inertia-common/tailwind.config.js)
It only scans `.vue` and `.php` files located on resources folder,

Since you are adding tailwind classes in JS file, you need to tell tailwind to scan JS file by adding it on `tailwind.config.js` inside `content` properties,

something like `'./resources/js/**/*.js'`

Comment: Oh that's what they meant `adding` in tailwind.config.js. The JS file itself.

Comment: I was thinking that the tailwind.config.js was already pre configured to check on vue files but the js was not included in the settings. Though I did solve it on a different way (created a separate vue itself for this) at least I learned something new